# Jquery : .replace &reg; not functioning

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Why doesn't this work?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/&reg;/g, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').replace(/®/g, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').replace("\u00AE" , '<sup>&reg;</sup>'));
        };
    );
</script>
```

Firebug in Firefox gives this in the console:
"SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

But, this breaks the Wordpress entirely...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/&reg;/g, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').replace(/®/g, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').replace("\u00AE" , '<sup>&reg;</sup>'));
        }
    );
</script>
```

The basic of this function is to find every single registration mark in the body, and replace it with "<sup>®</sup>"
If this function is capable in PHP as well, that's preferable.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve? The code seem unneccesary messy...

Comment: You need to escape special characters inside the regex. And replacing the entire site HTML is **never** a good idea.

Comment: Make it easier to narrow down the issue by splitting the multiple `replace`s up onto individual lines. If you wanted to use PHP instead look into output buffers and/or `preg_replace`

Comment: You're missing a `}` before the last `);` to close the `.ready(function() {`

Comment: Use jQuery instead of $ in WordPress. `jQuery("body")`

Comment: The goal is to take all ® and wrap them in a sub tag like thus: <superscript>®</superscript>

So PHP would be the best option, but I fear it'd put too heavy of a load on the server. 

This updated code, thanks to the commenters, breaks Wordpress
`<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(
 function() {
    jQuery("body").html(
   jQuery("body").html()
   .replace(/&reg;/g, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
   .replace(/®/g, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
   .replace("\u00AE" , '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
   )
  }
 );
</script>`

Comment: Which I'm guessing that means this works, but something inside wordpress breaks. (By break, I mean the page fails to load, white screen with the javascript run dynamic year in the top left from the footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seemed like the best thing to do was to go into the database and just run a sql query to replace all registration marks and wrap it in "" tags.

However, this did work on individual elements. (Like adeneo said, it's not a good idea to replace the entire site HTML... which broke the site for me)

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("h1").html(
            $("h1").html()
                .replace("®", "<sup>&reg;</sup>")
                .replace(/&reg;/g, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
                .replace(/®/g, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
                .replace("\u00AE" , '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
        ); 
    });
</script>
```